# Socket.io Client for Appcelerator (Titanium Application iOS)

Tags: socket.io, titanium, appcelerator, socket.io-1.0

I am building a Titanium based mobile application (iOS) in Appcelerator and want to connect it to Node.js(Socket.io) based server. For that I need a client side socket.io file which.

I tried to import the client side JS using 'require',

var io = require('socket.io');  //JavaScript Downloaded from here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

I am getting the following error: 
Script Error: Module "socket.io" failed to leave a valid exports object

Please let me know where I am going wrong or what is the way to use socket.io in Appcelerator.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: I came across this: http://iamyellow.net/post/39028991344/appcelerator-titanium-websockets-socket-io

Check with this.. this should work... i am able to use TiWS in my app but now since i have found this post and it's related git i am going  to try this as well

Comment: I have been using this fork in my app with a socket.io server on Heroku for over a year now. However it is using socket.io version 0.9.16 so it is not compatible with the newer version 1.0 and you need to watch the syntax differences.

Comment: Found this updated version of socket.io modded to work with TiWS, version 1.0.0 https://github.com/xChat/titanium-socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io_working_reformatted_v1.4.5.js.

The updated TiWS is here https://github.com/omorandi/tiws/blob/master/ios/net.iamyellow.tiws-iphone-1.0.0.zip

Thank @designbyind on TiSlack, he referred me to it!